# Show that $\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} \left(\frac{x-1}{2^x}\right) = \frac{e^{2t}}{(e^t - 2)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

As part of a section on moment generating functions, I found the probability mass function $(x-1)/2^x$ for a certain $X$, yielding this moment generating function:

$$M(t) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} \left(\frac{x-1}{2^x}\right)$$

I am asked to show that

$$M(t) = \frac{e^{2t}}{(e^t - 2)^2}$$

By expanding my series form of $M(t)$, I have shown that

$$M(t) = e^{2t} \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{8}e^t + \frac{3}{16}e^{2t} + \frac{4}{64}e^{3t} + \dots\right)$$

But I can't seem to get the right part of this into a form that agrees with $(e^t - 2)^{-2}$. I tried taking the Taylor series.

I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: You have $i$ for the index variable of the sum, but $i$ is nowhere in the summand. Is $x$ the same things as $i$?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, should be summed over x.

Comment: See it as $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x(\frac{e^t}{2})^x -\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}(\frac{e^t}{2})^x $.

The first one can be obtained by taking the derivative of the power series $(1-y)^{-1} = \sum y^n$ then setting $y = \frac{e^t}{2}$.

The second is a standard geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straight forward if you set $\boxed{u=\frac{e^t}2}$ and use

- $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}u^x$ and
- $\frac{u}{(1-u)^2} = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xu^x$

\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} \left(\frac{x-1}{2^x}\right)
& = & \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right)^x - \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right)^x \\
& = & \frac{\frac{e^t}{2}}{\left(1-\frac{e^t}{2} \right)^2} - \frac{e^t}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2} } \\
& = & \ldots \mbox{common denominator and collecting like terms } \ldots \\
& = & \frac{e^{2t}}{\left(2-e^t\right)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

First let's do a reindexing:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} e^{tx} \left(\frac{x-1}{2^x}\right) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{t(x+1)} \left(\frac{x}{2^{x+1}}\right) = \frac{e^t}{2} \sum_{x=1}^\infty x \left( \frac{e^t}{2} \right)^x $$

Then write the sum as a double sum and switch the order of summation:

$$ = \frac{e^t}{2} \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^x \left( \frac{e^t}{2} \right)^x = \frac{e^t}{2} \sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=y}^\infty \left( \frac{e^t}{2} \right)^x = \frac{e^t}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}} \sum_{y=1}^\infty \left( \frac{e^t}{2} \right)^y$$

$$ = \left(\frac{e^t}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}}\right)^2 = \frac{e^{2t}}{(2-e^t)^2}$$

of course assuming $t < \log 2$

Comment: Nice idea with the double sum (+1)